# Why does Bluetooth transfer from Windows Phone to PC fail to complete

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Nokia Lumia with Windows 10 and a Lenovo Pc with Windows 7 and i would like to send bluetooth files on my phone to the Pc. Now when sending files from PC the transfer completes very well without any problem. However the reverse is not true from my smartphone.
Now my phone and laptop are already paired so i do the following steps:

- On my pc i click receive files and it open a windows saying : Waiting for connection.
- Now when i tap share on my phone and choose my laptop
- The blue tooth transfer shows progress on both phone and laptop.
- Blue tooth transfer fails at around 30% regardless of the file size especially those above 500 kb.
- However for files below 500 kb the files are received on my laptop very well.

My android phone can send any type of file to my Lc and it will still be received. Is this a bug or security feature on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is a serious bug on windows phone that particularly affects its Bluetooth operations. Another thing maybe the laptop you are using has issues with its Bluetooth drivers.

The easiest way to transfer files from your Windows Phone 8 to your PC is by simply connecting it through USB. You then should see it as a USB device and access photos, music etc.

You can also synchronize your photos through One Drive and then download them on your Windows 8.1 machine.

If you need to use Bluetooth transfer, try using the "fsquirt" tool. http://plugable.com/2013/11/11/easy-way-to-use-bluetooth-to-exchange-files-with-your-phone-in-windows-fsquirt-guide

Comment: Facing same problem and did'nt find any sol -_-

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right there had been a bug and I was facing the same problem with my L535 and L950XL. Perhaps the bug has been addressed in the latest build. I don't know if the build fixes the problem or driver updation helped it out but I did following steps to resolve the problem:

1.Unpaired my phone  from the PC.

2.Deleted the device from PC as well.

3.Updated my phone to the build 14393.479.

4.Updated my PC drivers as well and installed all pending updates.

5.Then paired again and started sharing.

That worked for my L535. After which I tried for L950XL and amazingly it worked for that as well. Now I can share the files flawlessly and can also setup a Bluetooth personal area network among my two lumias and my PC. My PC is running W10 Enterprise if relevant. Hopefully this helps.